# Displaying single instance Name with additional criteria - INDEX & MATCH Function

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, office365, match

I have a set of multiple instances of names in column E and a respective number assigned to each name in column D.
I have used Formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$4:$E$12;MATCH(0;COUNTIF($H$3:H3;$E$4:$E$12);0);1);"")
```

in H4:H8 which works well for the extraction of single instance of the names from E4:E12.

[image]

Now I want to add one more criteria in the formula, to extract only names whose number from D4:D12 =4 and in the above example, the result would be only d instead of a,b,c,d,e.

I tried with COUNTIFS by adding additional criteria like:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$4:$E$12;MATCH(0;COUNTIFS($H$3:H3;$E$4:$E$12;$D$4:$E$12;$D$4:$D$12="4");0););"")
```

But nothing is displayed this time.

Any Idea, how this criteria should be added?

Comment: What version of Excel is it you are using? Also, why just `d` and not also `b`?

Comment: I am using office 365. only d because all instances of d have a number "4", whereas b has "3" and "4".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following with Microsoft365:

[image]

Formula in `H4`:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(E4:E12,COUNTIFS(E4:E12,E4:E12,D4:D12,"<>4")=0,""))
```

***Note:** Change the commas to semicolon for your locale if needed.*

Comment: that's amazing, thank you! 
In the above example, if  want to print only names based on number "3", I changed your formula to =UNIQUE(FILTER(E4:E12,COUNTIFS(E4:E12,E4:E12,D4:D12,"<>3")=0,"")) and nothing is printed. I know it is because of a and b existing with different numbers. But how to print the names with numbers 3, here a,b although they exist in other numbers?

Comment: @Ushay `=UNIQUE(FILTER(E4:E12,D4:D12=3,""))`. That is because your query is now completely different and you don't need to discard those names that also have other numbers. It get's easier that way.